# From AWS S3, PDF not opening in Chrome or Edge - Same PDF files opening properly from Firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, pdf, amazon-s3, microsoft-edge

We have our storage in S3 where we have stored smultiple PDF files - it seems that 50% of the files are not opening using EDGE | CHROME and it works fine with FIREFOX (see below 2 samples). Please note that they are behind a CDN and AWS Support is telling is this is a Edge | Chrome related issue.

https://d3b9jaoq7f5qjm.cloudfront.net/AKB/German/20034621/EVS9300_ReferencingLimitSwitch_conf.pdf
https://d3b9jaoq7f5qjm.cloudfront.net/AKB/German/202100250/Differenzbeschreibung_EASY_Starter_V1_20_1_de_.pdf

We captured the packets network using Developer Tools, Fiddler and Wiresharks however could not find anything suspicious.

Pl help here.

Regards.

Comment: The first step is to confirm that the uploaded size in S3 matches the size of the files on your local disk. Next, go to the S3 console and choose "Download" and verify the downloaded files are the same size and open correctly. Next, access the file via CloudFront and download it -- again check the file size. This should help you identify which step is causing the problem, especially whether "direct from S3" is behaving the same as "via CloudFront".

Answer (score 0):

Interesting!

When downloading from Firefox:

- File is 78K
- Contents starts with `%PDF-1.4`

When downloading from Chrome:

- File is 72K
- Contents is not PDF

When downloading via `curl` with `curl https://d3b9jaoq7f5qjm.cloudfront.net/AKB/German/20034621/EVS9300_ReferencingLimitSwitch_conf.pdf >file.pdf`:

- File is 78K
- Contents is a PDF (same as Firefox)

I wonder whether the differences are due to [HTTP compression - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)? Browsers know how to handle gzip-compressed data being sent and they automatically decompress it. I wonder whether this is being done correctly by Firefox and `curl`, but Chrome is seeing the smaller 72K file and isn't decompressing it?

You can determine whether this is happening by looking at the original file in S3 and seeing whether it is 72K or 78K. You could also download it from the S3 console and check the file size on your computer.

Comment: In AWS Console, the file property shows 76.7 KB - which means may be Chrome | Edge is not decompressing the file...

Comment: Thanks KJ for your inputs!
For example with the Edge 121.0.2277.112 (Official build) - the above files open properly as you described.
Then I tried with different pdf and the following ones are not opening (see next comment)

Comment: https://d3b9jaoq7f5qjm.cloudfront.net/AKB/German/20033695/EVF9300_MotorparameterBerechnung.pdf
https://d3b9jaoq7f5qjm.cloudfront.net/AKB/German/200412407/Anschlussbelegung_USB_PS2.pdf
http://d3b9jaoq7f5qjm.cloudfront.net/AKB/German/200413971/Appl_200_4_3_V1_0_PDO_EDS.PDF